# How to quickly check the continuity of a given function?

Tags: continuity

I would like to know if there was a given function, $f(x,y) = y\sqrt x$,how would I quickly check if the function is defined and continuous for $y(0) = 0$?

Note: Just wanna check the condition for Picard's theorem!

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by $y(0) = 0$?

Comment: Meaning (x,y) = (0,0)

Comment: What is the intended domain of $f$? Are $x$ and $y$ intended to belong to $\Bbb{R}$, $\Bbb{C}$ or what?

Comment: @misheekoh it seems my answer is not correct. please see comments below. and review accepted symbol to I be able to delete it. thank you

Comment: @RaziehNoori: your answer very likely is correct if the OP is really interested in the Picard-Lindelof theorem.

Comment: @RobArthan, What I was trying to ask is is the function f(x,y) continuous at the point (0,0). How would I quickly check for it? It seems that Razieh's answer is sufficient.

Comment: @msheekoh: yes, sorry about the misunderstanding. Why don't you give Razieh the tick back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f(x,y)=y \sqrt {x}$ where $x\in \mathbb{R}^{\geq 0}$, is product of two continuous functions thus it is continuous

Comment: $\sqrt{x}$ is continuous on $\Bbb{R}_{\ge0}$, but if the OP wants to apply Picard's theorem, I don't think that's good enough.

Comment: I amnot familiar with Picard's theorem. If you are sure this is not correct answer, let me know to delet it. I will be thankful.

Comment: Picard's theorem is about complex-valued functions of a complex variable (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard_theorem), but if the OP is happy with your answer, who am I to complain $\ddot{\smile}$?

Comment: :) i tried to delet it, but it is impossible. "you cannot delet this accepted answer"

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much. Why not just edit your answer to state the assumptions you've made about this not very clear question?

Comment: yes, good suggestion. thanks

Comment: @RobArthan i'm pretty sure the OP is referring to this Picard's theorem: [Picard-Lindelöf's theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard–Lindelöf_theorem) (not one of the complex analysis ones)

Comment: @mrf: you could well be right.

Comment: @mrf yes, That is the Picard theorem I'm looking at.

Comment: @RobArthan Not the complex variable Picard's Theorem.